# Adding a database result to an array and fill another respective array to the same database table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I have written a program to insert an array in all the rows of a column in a database table with respect to already filled column in the same database same table.

But it doesn't seems to work properly. Please tell me where I am going wrong!

```
$query = $sql = "SELECT A FROM `table`";
$result1 = mysql_query($query); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result1)) {

foreach($output as $value){
$count=sizeof($value); 

for($counter=0;$counter<$count;$counter++)
{

$query= "INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES ('" . $value . "') WHERE A= $row[$counter] ";

$insert_col= mysql_query($query);

echo $query;
echo '<br/><br/>';
  }} 

}
```

Where `$output` is an array contains the array value as follows:

```
$output[0]= RD 3.56 , $output[1]= RD 5.56 , $output[2]= RD 4.86
```

When I run my program, to check my the query .. the output comes like this:

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.144') WHERE A= 3r_1 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 2.436') WHERE A= 3r_1 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.624') WHERE A= 3r_1 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.60') WHERE A= 3r_1 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.60') WHERE A= 3r_1 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.60') WHERE A= 3r_1 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.144') WHERE A= 3r_2 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 2.436') WHERE A= 3r_2 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.624') WHERE A= 3r_2 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.60') WHERE A= 3r_2 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.60') WHERE A= 3r_2 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.60') WHERE A= 3r_2 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.144') WHERE A= 3r_3 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 2.436') WHERE A= 3r_3 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.624') WHERE A= 3r_3 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.60') WHERE A= 3r_3 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.60') WHERE A= 3r_3 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.60') WHERE A= 3r_3 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.144') WHERE A= 3r_4 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 2.436') WHERE A= 3r_4 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.624') WHERE A= 3r_4 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.60') WHERE A= 3r_4 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.60') WHERE A= 3r_4 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.60') WHERE A= 3r_4 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.144') WHERE A= 3r_5 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 2.436') WHERE A= 3r_5 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES (' RD: 1.624') WHERE A= 3r_5
```

Please help! i am going mad with this bug in my program for almost more than a week.

The output should look like this

```
INSERT INTO 'TABLE' SET B = ' RD: 1.144' WHERE A = '3r_1' 

INSERT INTO 'TABLE' SET B = ' RD: 2.436' WHERE A = '3r_2' 

INSERT INTO 'TABLE' SET B = ' RD: 1.624' WHERE A = '3r_3' 

INSERT INTO 'TABLE' SET B = ' RD: 1.560' WHERE A = '3r_4' 

INSERT INTO 'TABLE' SET B = ' RD: 1.560' WHERE A = '3r_5' 

INSERT INTO 'TABLE' SET B = ' RD: 1.560' WHERE A = '3r_6'
```

The problem here is `$row` value is repeated 6 times for all the `$output` values. How can I solve the problem?

And after lot of trials, I got to know that the problem is in calling the arrays. So, if anyone can tell me how to call the two arrays at the same time w.r.t the code written above, I would be very grateful.

Comment: How about $query= "INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES ('" . $value . "') WHERE A= '$row[$counter]' ";

Comment: tried ... but the problem is same "$row value is repeated 6 times for all the $output values"

Comment: The way your question has been asked is confusing. Maybe you should try re-framing it. Your problem is that you are not looping over the arrays correctly. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you have a looping problem.

You have 2 lists that you need to increment simultaneously.

Try this:

```
$value = [' RD: 1.144', ' RD: 2.436', ' RD: 1.624', ' RD: 1.560', ' RD: 1.560', ' RD: 1.560'];
$row = ['3r_1', '3r_2', '3r_3', '3r_4', '3r_5', '3r_6'];

$cnt = count($row);//assuming $row and $value are of the same size

for($i = 0; $i < $cnt, $i++) {
    echo "INSERT INTO 'TABLE' SET B = '$value[$i]' WHERE A = '$row[$i]' ";
}
```

This is a simpler example, but essentially, this is what you need to be doing.

Comment: ya very true i need to extract simultaneously. for that i need to call both the array simultaneously too. how can i do that.. please help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax :

```
$query= "INSERT INTO 'TABLE' SET B = '" . $value . "' WHERE A = '$row[$counter]' ";
```

By the way the table name 5 is extremly wierd.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to something more like this

```
$i = 1;
$query = "SELECT A FROM `table`";
$result1 = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result1)) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES ('" . $output[$i] . "') WHERE `A` = '".$row[0]."' ";

    $insert_col = mysql_query($query);

    $i++;

    echo $query;
    echo '<br/><br/>';

}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to match up. How does the array of outputs line up with the new table

Comment: i have already an array ($row) in a database table filled as a column named as "A" now i have another array value ($output) which has to be filled in another column with respect to the column  values of A

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result1)) {

foreach($output as $key=>$value){

$query = "INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`B`) VALUES ('" . $value . "') WHERE `A` = '".$row[$key]."' ";

$insert_col= mysql_query($query);

echo $query;
echo '<br/><br/>';
  }}
```

tried the same thing.. but getting the same output ...